# Was The Nightmare Before Christmas meant to be a Halloween or Christmas Movie?

Tags: genre, the-nightmare-before-christmas

When I first saw *The Nightmare Before Christmas* it was around during December when most series on free-to-air TV in Australia start to end for the year and take a break until near the end of January the next year. During this time most of the movies are Christmas themed but *The Nightmare Before Christmas* didn't seem like that at first.

#### About Halloween:

- Movie starts out and is generally set in Halloween Town with its dark scary look
- After learning about Christmas, Jack tries his take on it with some [scary looking presents](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N9tCN7Vayg)
- Santa was called Sandy Claws
- Lock, Shock and Barrel [had some very violent ideas of dealing with Sandy Claws](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ry7PcYtKPhA)

#### About Christmas:

- Jack was bored doing Halloween and after discovering it, wanted to do Christmas and most of the movie was Jack learning, preparing and doing Christmas
- Jack tries very much to [explain Christmas to the residents of Halloween Town](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7ftU2vxIC0) in which everything isn't all fights and scares
- from Jack's perspective his presents weren't bad but rather he focused on the nice box rather than the item inside like in the Town Hall Song he says the point is not to know what's in it and dismisses their guessing (in a way reinforced in the second chapter of Halloween Town in Kingdom Hearts 2 where Jack laments on the ruined boxes while he stepped on a toy that fad fallen out ignoring it)
- The Movie's climax was very much about saving Christmas much like most Christmas Movies

So I am wondering, was *The Nightmare Before Christmas* meant to be a Halloween or Christmas Movie?

Comment: Does it have to be either exclusively?

Comment: I agree with @NapoleonWilson. While there are valid answers to the question, I don't think we have to classify the movie. Last year I watched it around Halloween, this year in the weeks before Christmas.

Comment: *board <> bored

Comment: I'd say **both** :) That's the beauty of it

Comment: I heard its a base unit conversion joke. Oct 31 = Dec 25. As in 31 in Octal is 25 in Decimal

Comment: Not really answer worthy so i'll put it in the comments. Jack is Pumpkin King who has grown tired of his normal life. This whole movie is about Jack trying to do Christmas, but ultimately realizes that needs to stick to Halloween. So even if the director hadn't been quoted saying its a Halloween movie, I would still say its a Halloween movie even though Christmas is part of the plot

Comment: In the US I've noticed the TV networks seem to split the difference and play it around Thanksgiving.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4073/49).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**According to the film's director Henry Selick, it's supposed to be a Halloween Movie.**

According to [The Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-5020469/The-Nightmare-Christmas-sparks-debate-Twitter.html)

> Henry Selick, 64, who directed the 1993 film recently spoke about its themes at a Q&A at the Telluride Horror Show in Colorado.
>   He was asked whether the film is a Halloween or Christmas movie.
>   Henry explained that, while Christmas plays a factor in the story, at the end of the day, The Nightmare Before Christmas is a story about Halloween

And from [Entertainment Weekly](http://ew.com/article/2015/10/19/nightmare-before-christmas-halloween-or-christmas/)

> “It’s a Halloween movie,” Selick responded, finally putting the debate to rest.

Why? According to [this transcript](http://birthmoviesdeath.com/2015/10/18/nightmare-before-christmas-is-a-halloween-movie-says-director) the director stated:

> "It's a Halloween movie," he said, definitively. He acknowledged that a lot of people liked the Christmas Town stuff waaaaay better than the Halloween Town ("They love Santa and say he's all-powerful," he said), but he had to tell the truth: this is a movie about Halloween, and the people of Halloween, and how they react to something like Christmas.

Answer (score 39):

We can take the director's (Henry Selick) own word on this. From [dailymail.co.uk](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-5020469/The-Nightmare-Christmas-sparks-debate-Twitter.html)

> During the Q&A a little girl asked the director whether the animated film was a Christmas or Halloween movie, according to Hypable, to which he said 'Oh boy. It's a Halloween movie.'
>
> Henry then went on to explain that while Christmas plays a factor in the story, at the end of the day, The Nightmare Before Christmas is a story about Halloween, the citizens of Halloween Town and their reactions to the Christmas holiday.

Comment: Nice quote - I wish we had one from the writer, Tim Burton.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I tried a lot but got nothing yet

Comment: "Is it not better to take [author's] own word?"  3 out of 4 Lit teachers say no!

Comment: @Michael did those 3 teachers written the film?

Comment: It's a reference to something I read but cannot find at the moment about a teacher who had this grandiose interpretation about what a certain author's poem or other work meant, which when the author read tried to correct the teacher about.  Obviously if more authors did this the teachers would be unhappy that they are out of a job at (incorrectly) reading the minds of the authors or intuiting what they "really" meant and therefore might claim to know better than the author what his or her work really meant.

Comment: @Michael, *the death of the author*.

Answer (score 20):

According to [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107688/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt), the movie's original US release was in time for Halloween (29 October 1993), as were its re-releases.

Comment: I was about to post this as an answer. And one of the main songs is untitled "this is Halloween".

Comment: I think this, more than the director's intent, is the best way to tell.  If it were a Christmas movie, it'd have first come out in late November or December.

Comment: @Taladris the song is **titled** "this is Halloween". You probably meant to say *entitled* but that is incorrect as well.

Comment: @Theoriok: entitled, right. But I don't see why it is not correct

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't about either holiday. The film can be analyzed about the obsession with routines and bad habits. The movie is a scrutiny of the commercialization of the Holidays in general. You have two universes completely dedicated to the pursuits their holiday derives. The people of Halloween town despite their stoicism and over contentment are miserable and depressed. And a new pursuit, Christmas, motivates their new resolve, even though they have no understanding of the tradition. This marks the observance of how secular societies adopt various holidays with no understanding of how they originated or what they're celebrating. Which is shown by Jack's ignorance of gift giving and decorum, the result of which nearly ruins Christmas in the real world.

The film also critiques the corporate-ization of holidays in general. Namely the two largest of the year where heavy purchase and decoration are paramount; and the sore expectations children place on both. In the end Jack nearly ruins Christmas by mutilating the kids holiday with failure to get what they want. And the failure to adapt against status quo. Jack Skellington is otherwise a successful and important figure whom by his poor interpretation of Christmas makes society believe Santa has turned "oddly irrational" and seeks to express the same Christmas feelings having his citizens quickly engage in manufacture in products the children don't even want or need. The film is typical of Tim Burton's ongoing, cynical commentary on contemporary American culture, particularly consumer culture. The film also discusses other big business critiques in the film, including the unemployment of local workers, the declining quality of mass-produced products and the marketing of consumer products to children namely the pursuit of holiday productivity. In the end, the film rebuttals that Holidays are just that Holi[day], and should be celebrated one day only and the constant pursuit of these activities endlessly and recklessly is inherently tedious, vacuous and self destructive.

The film also investigates the necessity of core family values on Children. Sally is a creation of Professor Finkelstein. In the long run Sally's respect for the Professor is minimal, the professor keeps her under lock and key sheltering her from the world as a whole. Sally keeps the professor inundated and drugged to permit her freedom. Metaphor for alcoholism and drug abuse among parents and teens.

Answer (score -2):

The film was first released in October 1993 (USA cinematic release), it's a Halloween movie. Simple, huh?

It was released in Brazil in December 1993, specifically on the 24th of December. It's a Christmas movie. Simple, huh?

It was an October release in America, Japan and Argentina.

December (or November), however, was the first outing for the film in Brazil, Sweden, Australia, Hong Kong, Colombia, Hungary, Finland, The UK, Greece, Denmark, Spain, Italy, France, Germany, Austria, Portugal, The Netherlands, South Korea... The list goes on.

It seems the marketing bods knew that it could be sold for either holiday, and that it would be watched on either occasion. However, the world-wide concensus appears to be that it was a Christmas movie, which would bring in the most revenue when it's in the cinemas around Christmas and *after* Halloween.

My conclusion, then... **It's a Christmas movie**

Here's a full list of releases: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107688/releaseinfo